# ı am trying to get proxyies and ports ı get the proxyses but ı cant get the ports plese help me

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36"}
url = "https://www.proxyscan.io/"

r=requests.get(url,headers=headers)

soup = bs(r.content,"html.parser")
a = soup.findAll(scope="row")
a = str(a).replace("<th scope=\"row\">", "").replace("</th>", "").replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(" ","")
a = a.split(",")


for proxy in a:
    print(proxy)
```

Comment: Please ensure your title summarizes the specific problem like "How to extract a tag using BeautySoup which doesnot have a class" and then summarise what exactly the problem is like "not able to get port numbers". It would also be helpful if you could add some scrapped data structure so that someone can help you without actually running your code. Please check this link for improving question quality so that more people can help you https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find_next_siblings()` function to get the next available tag.

So by observing the parsed html keenly, we can see that port is next tag right after the proxy. Hence we can loop through variable `a` and find the next adjacent tags.

Get the first element from the array returned by `find_next_siblings()`.

Which would be something like this `<td>4145</td>`. Clean up the html tags from this or extract string from `td` and you should get the port number.

```
for i in a:
    full = i.find_next_siblings()[0]
    port = str(full).replace("<td>","")
    port = str(port).replace("</td>", "")
    print(port)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tedad/PycharmProjects/keylogger/denemee.py", line 16, in <module>
    full = i.find_next_siblings()[0]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_next_siblings'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Please write down this loop after `a = soup.findAll(scope="row")`. As from next step you are cleaning out the a tag, it is giving the error.

Comment: can ı send my anydesk code please help ı am triyng this for 38 hour

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36"}

url = "https://www.proxyscan.io/"
    
r=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    
soup = bs(r.content,"html.parser")

a = soup.findAll(scope="row")

a = str(a).replace("<th scope=\"row\">", "").replace("</th>", "").replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(" ","")

a = a.split(",")
    
    
for proxy in a: 
   print(proxy)
```

Comment: It is fine in principle to answer your own questions, but all you have done here is copy the same code that is in the question.